# Interface implementation has an extra argument in the function

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here is the definition of a member of ICommand : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute.aspx

The signature is:

```
 
void Execute(
    Object parameter
)
```

It is implemented by RoutedCommand with the following signature ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.execute.aspx ) :

```
public void Execute(
    Object parameter,
    IInputElement target
)
```

How can RoutedCommand Implement ICommand with an extra argument (IInputElement) in a member function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It uses [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) to "hide" the [`ICommand.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345569.aspx) method that takes a single parameter. The [`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.execute.aspx) method that takes two parameters *is not* an implementation of `ICommand.Execute`.

```
public class RoutedCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter, IInputElement target)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // explicit interface implementation of ICommand.Execute
    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was also surprised but got my query resolved here too.

Answer (score 1):

The ICommand.Execute() interface method is implemented explicitly.  Docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345569).